# NodeJS - Extract data from a multilevel array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have the following JSON array :

```
{
"list": [{
    "name": "Assignment",
    "id": 67,
    "template": 0,
    "children": [{
        "assignmentnumber": 1000,
        "fromCountry": "Sweden",
        "toCountry": "Spain",
        "fromCity": "Stockholm",
        "toCity": "Madrid"
    }, {
        "assignmentnumber": 15678,
        "fromCountry": "Sweden",
        "toCountry": "Germany",
        "fromCity": "Stockholm",
        "toCity": "Berlin"
    }, {
        "assignmentnumber": 10001,
        "fromCountry": "Sweden",
        "toCountry": "United Kingdom",
        "fromCity": "Stockholm",
        "toCity": "London"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Valuation form",
    "id": 36,
    "template": 0,
    "children": [15678]
}, {
    "name": "Claim",
    "id": 12,
    "template": 0,
    "children": [1000, 10001]
}]
}
```

I need to extract a new array from the array containing only the 'name' element. I have tried lodash but cannot figure out how to use it properly.

Anyone who can give me a clue how to do this ?

Comment: @JPlexor, it is working for you ?

Comment: It works like a charm ;-) Thank you all !

Answer (score 4):

You should use `map` method, which accepts as parameter a `callback` function.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

```
var array=obj.list.map(callback);
function callback(item){
    return item.name;
}
```

Or simply:

```
var array=obj.list.map(el=>el.name);
```

```js
var obj={
"list": [{
    "name": "Assignment",
    "id": 67,
    "template": 0,
    "children": [{
        "assignmentnumber": 1000,
        "fromCountry": "Sweden",
        "toCountry": "Spain",
        "fromCity": "Stockholm",
        "toCity": "Madrid"
    }, {
        "assignmentnumber": 15678,
        "fromCountry": "Sweden",
        "toCountry": "Germany",
        "fromCity": "Stockholm",
        "toCity": "Berlin"
    }, {
        "assignmentnumber": 10001,
        "fromCountry": "Sweden",
        "toCountry": "United Kingdom",
        "fromCity": "Stockholm",
        "toCity": "London"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Valuation form",
    "id": 36,
    "template": 0,
    "children": [15678]
}, {
    "name": "Claim",
    "id": 12,
    "template": 0,
    "children": [1000, 10001]
}]
};
console.log(obj.list.map(function(item){
    return item.name;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without lodash, using native Array APIs.

```
const obj = { /* The JSON in your question */ };
const names = obj.list.map(item => item.name);
```

`Array.map()` takes a function and calls that function on each item of an array, returning a new array containing the result of each item.

Answer (score 0):

Map is the best way to go as everyone else stated. Another alternative is use a forEach loop, specially if you want to operate with them.

```
var children = obj.children;
var array_of_names;

children.forEach(function (item)){
    array_of_names.push(item.name);
    //... Do more operations for each item
}
```